# Angular 2 RC6 problems with SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm having some problems getting my app to run after updating to RC6.

I changed my systemjs due to the official example [from changelog](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/systemjs.config.js#L17-L34).

But I still get compile errors like this one:
"Module '"D:/Myproject/WebClient/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES'."

It looks like the compiler takes the default index.js file instead the umd package... The compiling is done by gulp task with the following options:

`"module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false`

I get this errors for router module and forms module.

Router is V3.0.0-rc.2 and forms is V.2.0.0-rc6

Think it is more a problem that my systemJs is not read correctly anyhow.

SystemJS:

```
var map = {
'app': 'public/app',
'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
'@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
'@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
'@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
'@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
'@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
'symbol-observable': 'npm:symbol-observable',
'moment': 'npm:moment',
'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts',
'ng2-translate/ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate',
'angular2-highcharts': 'npm:angular2-highcharts',
'highcharts/highstock.src': 'npm:highcharts',
'primeng': 'npm:primeng'
};

var packages = {
'app': { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs': { main: 'Rx.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
'moment': { main: 'moment', defaultExtension: 'js', type: 'cjs'},
'symbol-observable': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-charts': { main: 'ng2-charts', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-translate/ng2-translate': { main: 'ng2-translate', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-highcharts': { main: 'index', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'highcharts/highstock.src': { main: 'highstock.src', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'primeng': { defaultExtension: 'js' }s
};


System.config({
map: map,
packages: packages,
paths: {
    // paths serve as alias
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
}
//format: 'register'
});
```

Aynbody any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per new change in rc6 deprecated directives are removed and for default angular functionality `ngModule` is introduced in rc5 so you have to configure `RouterModule` from `@angular/router` as per [Routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) documentation to configure your routes and then you can use directives provided by `RouterModule`.

Comment: Thanks, there are some more problems with other external packages, but basically it runs with removing all the directives.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, `FORM_DIRECTIVES` and `CORE_DIRECTIVES` from all your components. Instead, create modules for all components. Import `BrowserModule` in your `AppModule` and import `FormModule` for all Modules you need form directives for.

Further information can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

An AppModule looks e.g. like the following:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}   from './app.component';
// Other imports are removed

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, LoginModule, routing],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    Logger,
    LOG_LOGGER_PROVIDERS,
    AuthenticationService,
    AccountService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule {
}
```